# Conditional Cloud Builds with Many Packages in a Monorepo

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, build-automation, google-cloud-build, monorepo

## Motive

I want to fully automate the deployment of many **services** with the help of [Google Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/) and [Google Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/). Those services are located inside a **monorepo**, which has a folder called `services`.

So I created a `cloudbuild.yaml` for every service and created a build trigger. The `cloudbuild.yaml` does:

1. run tests
2. build new version of Docker image
3. push new Docker image
4. apply changes to Kubernetes cluster

## Issue

As the number of services increases, the number of build triggers increases, too. There are also more and more services that are built even though they haven't changed.

Thus I want a mechanism, which has only **one** build trigger and automatically determines which services need to be rebuild.

## Example

Suppose I have a monorepo with this file structure:

```
├── packages
│   ├── enums
│   ├── components
└── services
    ├── backend
    ├── frontend
    ├── admin-dashboard
```

Then I make some changes in the `frontend` service. Since the `frontend` and the `admin-dashboard` service depend on the `components` package multiple services need to be rebuild:

- frontend
- admin-dashboard

But **not** backend!

## What I've Tried

#### (1) Multiple build triggers

Setting up multiple build triggers for **every** service. But 80% of those builds are redundant, since most changes in the code are only related to individuals services. It's also increasingly complex to manage many build triggers, which look almost identical. A single `cloudbuild.yaml` file looks like this:

```
steps:
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args:
      [
        "build",
        "-f",
        "./services/frontend/prod.Dockerfile",
        "-t",
        "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/frontend:$REVISION_ID",
        "-t",
        "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/frontend:latest",
        ".",
      ]
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    args: ["push", "gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/frontend"]

  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl"
    args: ["apply", "-f", "kubernetes/gcp/frontend.yaml"]
    env:
      - "CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=europe-west3-a"
      - "CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=cents-ideas"
```

#### (2) Looping through cloudbuild files

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861870) question is about a very similar issue. So I've tried to set up one "entry-point" `cloudbuild.yaml` file in the root of the project and looped through all services:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
    for d in ./services/*/; do
      config="${d}cloudbuild.yaml"
      if [[ ! -f "${config}" ]]; then
        continue
      fi

      echo "Building $d ... "
      (
        gcloud builds submit $d --config=${config}
      ) &
    done
    wait
```

This would eliminate the need for having multiple build triggers. But I also ran into issues with this method:

Every service is sent into it's own build process with the file scope of this particular service. This means, that I can only access files inside `/services/specific-service` during the build. Which is a total bummer for me (I need access to files in parent directories like `packages` and config files in the root).

#### (3) Build only changed services

Since I want a mechanism to only build changed services, I've tried to determine the services that need to be rebuilt. It seems quite easy to do this with the help of [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna). Running

```
lerna changed --all --parseable
```

will return a list file paths to the changed packages like this:

```
/home/username/Desktop/project/packages/components
/home/username/Desktop/project/services/frontend
/home/username/Desktop/project/services/admin-dashboard
```

However, the list also includes `packages` and I have no idea how I would be able to use this list in a script to loop through affected services. Also: when I trigger a build (e.g. through tagging a commit), lerna wouldn't be able to recognize changed packages during the build process as the changes have already been committed.

---

I know this is a long one. But I think it's an important topic, so I really appreciate any help!

P.S.: [This](https://github.com/flolude/cents-ideas/tree/develop) is how my actual project looks like, if you want to take a close look at the specific use-case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To build from a **monorepo** you really want to build incrementally (what is changed and parts that depends on changed parts). To achieve this, your build tool need to handle a dependency graph in some way.

Lerna that you describe is designed for monorepos. But so is also [Bazel](https://bazel.build/) and it is available as an option in Google Cloud Builder, [cloud-builders/bazel](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/bazel) with documentation for using in combination with a docker builder.

However, build tools designed for monorepos are usually more complex to setup.

Comment: that seems like a good approach! it would be awesome if you could include an example on how to implement it with multiple services :)

Comment: @flolu my experience is that it is a bit complex to setup, but I guess you want something like this: https://blog.mgechev.com/2018/11/19/introduction-bazel-typescript-tutorial/

Comment: Alright, I need to take a deeper look at it until I check your answer

Comment: also related https://dataform.co/blog/typescript-monorepo-with-bazel/